# MS Teams Online meetings - email notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to use MS Graph API 1.0 (endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings) to create online meetings for our customers.
Everything works fine and the meeting is created but participants (and organizer too) never received any email notifications about upcoming meetings.
Is there any configuration we need to enable for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you create any onlinemeetings it doesn't show up in user calendars, as this is by-design. I am not aware of any other settings/parameters available and its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) doesnt talk about that as well.